# How do I add a android folder to my current project?

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I downloaded a custom calendar and decided put them into my project.

I have `copy+pasted` onto my working folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you can see from the second picture, you see the folder 'app'. I am trying to also add 'library' folder you see from first photo to the same one. Yes, they are in the same working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one more thing to make that library folder usable in your app. Right click on app folder -> Open Module Settings -> Add library folder as module dependency following this screenshot

[image: Add module dependency]

Comment: There is nothing show when I click on the 'Module Dependency'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy & paste go to file->new->import module
Open module dependancies->in dependancies tab->add module dependancy->select library
Then also the library is not added then goto settings.gradle and add like this

```
include ':app',':library_name'
```